# iterate over all parameters based on an identifier using apache velocity

Tags: velocity

I am using Apache Velocity Template to generate an email body using parameters which are set in the SOA based event from java service.

In java we set parameters for the SOA event which we fire. The parameters are set like this:

```
createSOAEventParam(uow, soaEvent.getEventId(), "startedOn", startedOn);
createSOAEventParam(uow, soaEvent.getEventId(), "lastRunDate", new DateTime().toString());
```

We also set the file name and file size for associated in each sub process as follows:

```
**for(String subProcess : subProcesses){
            File file = new File(GOLD_DIR + subProcess + ".dat");
            if(file!=null && file.exists()){
                createSOAEventParam(uow, soaEvent.getEventId(), file.getName(), String.valueOf(file.length()));
            }
        }**
```

Now My task is to retrieve these parameters in the Application Resources which has an entry for the email body where I print out these parameters using VTL.
Something Like this:

```
label.Interfaces.FailureMessage.body=
<html>[label.LastSubmittedDate]: #if($startedOn != "") $startedOn  #end <br/> 
[label.FileName]: (iteration logic here)  [label.FileSize]: (iteration logic here)<br/>
```

I need to iterate over all parameters which have a **".dat"** at the end since they stand for file names and - which is the eventname in the java code and also get the file size which is the value of the event name.
How do I perform this iteration in VTL?

Comment: Your question is very unclear... I think a lot of the information is not relevant. i.e. what is `[label.LastSubmittedDate]` included for? why do we need to know about SOA events?

Comment: those are the labels which are resolved at run time, and SOA events are just the way the parameters are passed to velocityEngine

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for...

```
#foreach( $event in $eventList )
    #if( $event.name.endsWith(".dat") )
        ## do whatever
    #end
#end
```

Comment: Thanks..just a question- is $eventList a velocity variable for all parameters? I am not setting anything in the SOA events like $eventList, I looked up some places and will something like this work:   $eventList = $httpUtil.getParameterMap($httpUtil.getQueryString($request.attributes.CURRENT_URL))

Comment: So you want to read the http parameters from within the template? It would probably be more sensible to set the values you want as variables in the velocity context

Comment: I actually have all parameters set in the context, I just need to know how can I iterate through the context to retieve all params which have name ending with ".dat"

Comment: more exactly: #foreach( $event in $<all_parameters>), if all the parameters are in context how do I access that list?

Comment: So you aren't interested in the http parameters! You are interested in the **variables** in the velocity context. What you think you need to do seems wrong. When you set up the variables in the velocity context then perhaps you could put all the ".dat" ones or all the variables which are files into a single map or list

Comment: you dont know the entire picture.. The SOA event can only take strings as params so we cannot set Maps/List in it. Thats the reason we are setting each individual file name and file size in the SOA event params.